# Javascript back on two consecutive pages

Tags: back, javascript

So, I ran into a problem: I have 2 (or more) consecutive pages, which the user can click through. At the bottom of each page there's a "Back" button (with Javascript's history.go(-1);), so that the user is able to go back to the previous view.

Now my problem is: When the user is on page 3 and clicks on the button, he goes back to page 2 (until here everything's fine), but when he's back on page 2 and clicks on the back button on that page, instead of going even further back to page 1, he gets sent back (or forward?) to page 3.
Is there a solution to this problem, I tried Google, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you are asking this question - you don't understand the browser history behaviour and JavaScript capabilities - you should read about it and learn. When you know enough you will find alternatives to Richard's answer yourself.

Comment: Since javascript:history.go(-1); should emulate the browser's back-button, and pressing the back button twice does exactly what I tried to do, I assumed there would be a way to do it in JavaScript as well.
I do know there are many alternatives, I just wanted to avoid them. Oh well, seems like I'll have to stick to direct links.

Comment: If you follow the progression page 1 -> page 2 -> page 3 (...) and than use history.go(-1) than it will behave in the same way as browser's back button. On the other hand if you do any processing (post/get requests to server) on page 2 than it will rewrite your browser's history and this way you will find yourself in page 2 that happened to be **AFTER** page 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the Javascript is behaving exactly as it should in returning the browser to the previous page. Could you not handle your navigation between pages more explicitly? Replacing the history.go(-1) with a link to the actual script\page?

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to use direct links, because of some problems this would create. But since there doesn't seem to be a way of solving it just with JavaScript, I think I'll have to implement the direct links.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No worries mate, if the pages are being dynamically served up from server side scripting, you could track the user's progress there and serve up pages accordingly. Might be overkill for you requirement though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location` to send the user back to previous page instead of `history.go(-1)`. If the user lands on the second page in your flow, the back button will be useless.